# Summing numeric, when numeric is a string that can be converted to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, args

For this purpose i have created a function called sum_numeric() that takes any number of arguments and then if an argument is numeric type it is added to total, if not it is passed. But if type is string that can be converted to integer it should convert it and also add it to total.

```
   def sum_numeric(*args):
      total = 0
      for i in args:
         if type(i) == int:
            total += i
         elif type(i) == str:
            pass
       return total
   sum_numeric(1,2,3,'20','d',6)
```

Output of my code is

```
   12
```

instead of

```
   32
```

I have tried things like:

```
   def sum_numeric(*args):
      total = 0
      for i in args:
         if type(i) == int:
            total += i
         elif type(int(i)) == int:
            total += i 
         else:
            pass
      return total
   sum_numeric(1,2,3,'20','d')
```

But it gave me a

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

How to convert it to integer without having a ValueError or TypeError?

Comment: Check if the string `isnumeric` first? `try:` the conversion and catch the error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did 
elif i.isnumeric():
      i = int(i)
      total += i

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_numeric(*args):
    total = 0
    for i in args:
        if type(i) == int:
            total += i
        elif type(i) == str:
            try:
                total += int(i) # convert string to integer
            except:
                pass  # in case of errors
    return total

sum_numeric(1, 2, 3,'20','d', 6)
```

Output:

```
32
```